# Cookie persistence and best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In our application there are two types of user, let's call them `Alpha` and `Beta` users. Each of these users sees a different type of toolbar / menu.

We have decided to track this using cookies. The majority of our pages are either `Alpha` pages or `Beta` pages and then there are some common pages that `Alpha` and `Beta` users share. So in each view of our application where we know the user type (`Alpha` or `Beta`) we have the following code:

```
HttpCookie isAlphaCookie = new HttpCookie("IsAlpha", "false"); // or true
HttpCookie isBetaCookie = new HttpCookie("IsBeta", "true"); // or false

isAlphaCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
isBetaCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;

Response.Cookies.Add(isAlphaCookie);
Response.Cookies.Add(isBetaCookie);
```

The idea is then, in common pages, we don't set any cookie and rely on the previously set cookie to determine which toolbar to load. So, these two cookies are set to `true` or `false` as above in our known pages before we read them in the controller method which loads our toolbar like so:

```
HeaderViewModel header = new HeaderViewModel
{
    FirstName = UserProfile.CurrentUser.FirstName,
    LastName = UserProfile.CurrentUser.LastName,
    ImageUrl = null,
    OrganisationName = UserProfile.CurrentUser.OrganisationName,
    OrganisationUrl = UserProfile.CurrentUser.OrganisationUrl,
    ShowAlphaToolbar = bool.Parse(Request.Cookies["IsAlpha"].Value),
    ShowBetaToolbar = bool.Parse(Request.Cookies["IsBeta"].Value),
    ShowPublicToolbar = false
};

return PartialView("Common/_Header", header);
```

From reading up on how to read / write cookies this seems to be the right approach; writing the cookie to the `Response` object and reading the cookie from the `Request` object.

The problem I'm having is that when i get to the controller method that loads the toolbar the values of the `IsAlpha` and `IsBeta` cookies are both empty strings and this breaks the application.

I have confirmed that the cookies are set in the `Response` before they are read in the `Request`.

I'm wondering whether I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Try using some browser tools or Fiddler to see if the cookies are really being stored by the browser and sent back to the server during requests.

Comment: How do you call your partial action which includes the toolbar? Through ajax or through @Html.RenderAction()?

Comment: Check the `ExpiryDate` set into the cookie.

Comment: @Ankit The toolbar is loaded using `@Html.Action("LoadHeader", "Profile")`. If this won't work for me can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: Do you protect these cookies at all? From what you've said above, it would be trivial for the user to change the cookie value & change their user type. Look either encrypting the string, or adding a MAC to it so it' can't be tampered with.

Comment: @SimonHalsey Currently these cookies aren't protected. As it stands they could (in theory) alter these cookies on the client-side to view the other toolbar but the options and links inside the toolbar are all protected with permissions checks. So my real problem as the moment is persisting these cookies

Answer (score 0):

I only expect your assumption " in common pages, we don't set any cookie and rely on the previously set cookie to determine which toolbar to load" to work if you are calling these partial actions, which you referring to as "common pages" I guess, through Ajax Calls. If you are using

`@Html.RenderAction('nameOfaAtion')`

then I don't think what you have in place will work.

Reason is Both your main action and partial actions are executed within the same Http Request Cycle so the cookies you are trying to access from the Request Object in your common pages have not yet came as part of Request.

**Edit**

As I can see you are hard coding the cookies on each page so Guess you can also do something like below. Not originally the way you are trying to do but I think it will do the same thing you are trying.

In your pages change the partial view call to like this.

```
@Html.Action("LoadHeader", "Profile", new{IsAlpha=False, IsBeta=true});
```

Then Change the signature of the LoadHeader action to receive these two extra parameters

```
public ViewAction LoadHeader(bool IsAlpha, Bool IsBeta)
```

Then with the viewModel Initialization change two lines as below.

```
ShowAlphaToolbar = IsAlpha, 
ShowBetaToolbar = IsBeta,
```

Comment: The toolbar is loaded using `@Html.Action("LoadHeader", "Profile")`. If this won't work for me can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: Or best if you can use ajax to load this partial view. I guess you wouldn't need to change anything else then.

Comment: The problem I see with the edited answer above is with the "common" pages I described in my OP. I won't be setting any params (IsAlpha or IsBeta) in these pages and will need to know what values were set on the previous page. I'd love to be doing something like that but don't think it's possible for my scenario. I'm considering using a combination of `Cookies` and `TempData`. The reason I'm not using `TempData` across the board is we use multiple instances of Azure and cannot be sure what instance we are setting `TempData` on. But if `TempData` is used in the one request we should be ok